# Fantom loging to a remote web in code

Tags: uri, webclient, fantom

Hi I'm really new to Fantom and I'm trying to do a few of things.
I desire to access a data response in a server with a uri.

```
Void gets(){

str := WebClient(webpage).getStr
}
```

But when I try to connect I revie a 401 error.
What's the best way for to send the loggin and password to the server?

Thanks for read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what authentication is used by the server.

Example, if it the server uses [Basic HTTP Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) then you need to set the `Authorization` HTTP header:

```java
using web

class Example {
  Void main() {
    client := WebClient(`http://www.example.com/`)
    client.reqHeaders["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "username:password".toBuf.toBase64
    result := client.getStr
  }
}
```

If it uses a different authentication method, then you'll need to read up and implement that.

Note that you need to create a new `WebClient` instance for each HTTP request, else you'll get strange errors!